# Design chat application to have chat between admin and client only(not client to client) in android

Tags: android, android-studio

Design chat application to have chat between admin and client only(not client to client) in android.
It will be help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out. Its a sample application for learning to use firebase for a chat app. You can learn and create your own app as per your requirements.
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#0